# Codeception click input radio

Tags: testing, codeception

on my website i'm starting to use codeception to perform the tests.
On a page i have a form that has some fields to fill with data to perform the email test content. The problem is that this form have some input type radio. This inputs are inside on a div. On the end of this post will give the example to get a better perception of my problem. My problem is that i can't check this input. I had tried to used checkOption, selectOption, click functions and they simply don't work.
Here is some html:

http://pastebin.com/mDDZmAYv#

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have also two radio buttons inside a div and I have used code like this

```
$I->selectOption('.radio-tab:nth-child(1)', '2'); // if you have multiple radio button
```

In your cases you can use like this:

```
$I->selectOption('.form-radio, '123'); //accessing by class name and giving value.
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you using Codeception (Webdriver, PHPUnit, etc)?

if you are using it in PHP and WebDriver try this:

$I->click('[name=[event_id"]');

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the options above are not working, for me at least, I found something. If you use the WebDriver for Acceptance Tests try:

```
$I->click('label[for="id_of_your_option"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

For tricky UI stuff you could use executeJS method, so with native JS:

```
$I->executeJS('document.getElementById("edit-").checked = true;');
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$I->executeJS('$("edit-").prop("checked", true);');
```

For unchecking obviously just use false.